# Get Notifications with Facebook Graph API 2.4

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Pre 2.4 it seems you could return notifications using:

```
graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/notifications
```

But the permissions that this requires have since been deprecated (`manage_notifications`). What's the new way to get them?

[Example using the graph explorer.](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fnotifications)

For me it returns:

> (#200) Requires extended permission: manage_notifications

But there is no option to allow this permission through the "Get Token" box (I assume because it is now deprecated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no new way, it is just not possible anymore. If there will ever be a new way, it will be announced in the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog).

Comment: that means from api v2.4 onwards we can't able to fetch user notification?

Comment: exactly, that is what "not possible" means